# Firebase SMS authentication sign-in methods

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this Android code for Firebase sign in using SMS code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        userLoggedIn();
        
        mPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        mCode = findViewById(R.id.code);
        mSend = findViewById(R.id.send);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mVerificationId != null) {
                    // verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, mCode.getText().toString());
                    verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, mCode.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    startPhoneNumberVerification();
                }
            }
        });

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredentials(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);

                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mSend.setText("Verify Code");
            }

        };
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredentials(credential);;
    }

    private void startPhoneNumberVerification() {

        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(mPhoneNumber.getText().toString())       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();

        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredentials(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    userIsLoggedIn();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void userIsLoggedIn() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPageActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
```

The code works fine BUT after I added the following 2 sign-in methods on firebase project console, the app doesn't require new users to verify the SMS code any more - meaning, new users get signed in automatically after getting the code without punching in the code on the app.

**Firebase Authentication Sign-in providers console**

> Google
> Google sign-in is automatically configured on your connected iOS and
> web apps. To set up Google sign-in for your Android apps, you need to
> add the [SHA1 fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth?authuser=0) for each app on your Project Settings.
>
> Email/password
> Allow users to sign up using their email address and password. Our
> SDKs also provide email address verification, password recovery, and
> email address change primitives. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?authuser=0)

I have both SHA-1 and SHA-256 configures on my project.

Any ideas why it signs **new** users in automatically without verifying SMS code sent?

Comment: Once a user is signed in by any means, they stay signed in until you explicitly sign them out.

Comment: who said they are signed in??? `a new user gets signed in automatically after getting the code without punching in the code on the app page`

Comment: Firebase Auth automatically signs in users who were previously signed in.  That might explain what you're observing.  Feel free to ignore this comment if it's not helpful.  Consider also improving your question by explaining in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  It's good to have enough information in the question that anyone can reproduce the issue from start to finish.

Comment: Sorry but you're obviously misunderstanding my question. I specifically said new users and not verified. Is that not understood from my question??

Comment: Feel free to improve your question as I suggested.  It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Instant verfication might be happening with your phone number.
I have observed that with our numbers most of times Auto-retrieval works.

I'm guessing this behavior might be happening based on service provider/country code/device or other factors.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential

```
onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential)
```

This method is called in two situations:

> Instant verification: in some cases the phone number can be instantly
> verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.

> Auto-retrieval: on some devices, Google Play services can
> automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform
> verification without user action. (This capability might be
> unavailable with some carriers.)

In either case, the user's phone number has been verified successfully, and you can use the PhoneAuthCredential object that's passed to the callback to sign in the user.